# Ionic and html output

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework

I call via $http.get a json file, but the ionic view doesn't render the output correctly:

```
    loadNews() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
        this.http.get('http://www.mywebsite.it/public/index.php/api/news/5') 
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                resolve((data));
            });
    });
}
```

And the output is [image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you use angular property-binding?

Try:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

instead of:

```
<div>{{ data }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. So simple, so correct. Thanks. Thanks.